# Possible to run a Python script within a Laravel 4.1. PHP project for a callback for external widget?

Tags: php, python, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make an external widget, and I am trying to follow the basic tutorial seen here:

http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

I am using the Laravel framework for my main app, and I am trying to keep the widget files within the framework as well.  Is it possible to run the callback with a Python script within the framework?  Or would I need to adapt this to PHP?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why does it need to be a python script?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't, but do not know how to implement the server side code with php for the callback.

Comment: Can I run this callback in one of my laravel controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you convert this to PHP to avoid running (and setting permissions needed) "exec" calls on external scripts. However, I don't really have enough information to make a judgement on what's best.

If you are just implementing jsonp, then we can easily help convert that. (Can you explain or show the Python script?)

If you are using Python alongside PHP, you can set up Python to run as a CGI/FastCGI process (perhaps with [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)). However the ability to do that depends on your hosting and could use a little baseline server knowledge to accomplish (altho there's nothing super complex going on there if you want to learn more about it!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to call extenal applications and get the output:

```
exec('/usr/scripts/script.py', $output, $return);

if ( ! $return) {
    throw \Exception('Error running script '.__FILE__);
}

var_dump($output);
```